# Drawing a bitmap in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, image, graphics, bitmap

I am trying to simply draw an image from my resources folder onto a windows form, but for some reason it is not showing up, here is the code that I am attempting to use...I have been reading and searching for a while about the Graphics class and drawing in C# and I cant seem to understand it very well...any help or comments are greatly appreicated

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.BoostNeddleTest);
Graphics m_graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
m_graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 100, 100);
```

The Image is not being drawn, I'm not entirely sure why.

Comment: Where do you want to display the image? Have you tried using a [`PictureBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx)?

Comment: On the form, I have another image that I want to draw over this one, so I wasn't really sure how to use multiple PictureBox items

Comment: use `using` around the Graphics so it's properly closed and cleaned up and the changes are applied to the image.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this VRKnight

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
   Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.BoostNeddleTest);
   // Draw using this   
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp,100,100);
   base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

you can read more about OnPait Override here
[Overriding the OnPaint Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cksxshce.aspx)

Comment: Ah ok! I have seen this before, but how do I trigger the PaintEvent?

Comment: To override an inherited event

    Override the protected OnEventName method.

    Call the OnEventName method of the base class from the overridden OnEventName method, so that registered delegates receive the event.

Answer (score 0):

The way the `Graphics` object works is like this:-

```
 destination.DrawImage (source, position, etc...)
```

and in your code, the destination is the same as the source! Your `m_graphics` needs to be a display device (screen or printer), the `Graphics` object you need to use is given to you in the OnPaint methods of the WinForm.